# Iterating through an array and extracting elements that satisfy a condition in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to extract the elements in an array that do not vary (within some tolerance) from the next element.

I have some column vector, say, `m = [1; 3; 6; 8; 12]`. I therefore want to extract the elements that satisfy `m2 = abs(diff(m)) < 3`. Is this the correct way to create a new array `m2` whose elements are the difference between adjacent elements of `m`?

My problem is then extracting the elements of `m` that satisfy the condition set out by `m2`.

In reality I have a 9x4096 array and would therefore like to know which elements of `m` were used to give the elements of `m2`.

Comment: Are you asking whether the syntax of `m2 = abs(diff(m)) < 3 ` is correct or are you asking whether the formula is correct?

Comment: "My problem is then connecting..." What exactly is the problem that you have with connecting them? Be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As elements of `m2` is logical `0/1`, you can use `find()` to extracting the elements and according indexes that you want.

```
m = [1; 3; 6; 8; 12];
m2 = abs(diff(m)) < 3;
ind = find(m2);   % stores the indexes of elements that you want
m3 = m(m2);       % stores the values that you want
```

then

```
ind =
     1
     3    

m3 =
     1
     6
```

After this, `ind` stores the indexes of elements that you want and `m3` are the according values.

Comment: I wish to then extract the elements of m that give rise to the output of ind, because in reality I have a 9x4096 array and wish to know what elements of m that those results came from.

Comment: @Angelo Updated. `ind` for the indexes and `m3` for the values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) and in fact MATLAB will suggest this if you type this into a MATLAB editor. That's because logical indexing is significantly faster than using `find` esp. for very large arrays such as yours.

```
>> m = [1; 3; 6; 8; 12];   % <5x1 double>
>> m2 = abs(diff(m)) < 3;  % <5x1 logical>
>> m3 = m(m2);  %            <2x1 double>
>> m3
m3 =
    1
    6
>> m2
m2 =
    1
    0
    1
    0
```

Only use find when you must know the value of the index and not just the indexed value.

```
>> ind = find(m2);
>> ind
ind =
    1
    3
```

Comment: This is good for getting values, but `find()` can also achieve the according indexes, i.e. `1 3` in this case, which is better than logical index `1 0 1 0`.